# Gitlab pipeline can't find HEAD commit for this branch

Tags: gitlab-ci

When I commit on a my self-hosted Gitlab it triggers a new pipeline.
But most of the time I have  the following message instead of the real commit message.

> Can't find HEAD commit for this branch

[image]

This is not the case for every commit but I couldn't find any documentation about this.
It is not blocking but it would be great if I could see my commit messages.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: This error is not happening anymore. I suspect this is happeningonly to the x firsts commits.

Comment: Apparently, this can happen if you commit with no title but only a description, when using Git GUI tools for example (like GitKraken. etc.)